# How to quickly generate C++ projects arborescence

Tags: c++, makefile

I would like to generate a project architecture quickly, with a makefile already configured (like a mvn quickstart in Java).
For instance, a `make quickstart` would create me a repository like this :

```
makefile
main.cpp
src
```

with the makefile alread configured to compile and link sourcefiles in `src` with `main`. I then just have to add libs and directoies in src.

I suppose it's possible to do so wich Qmake or Cmake, but I don't know where to look or what terms to search.
Would you guys know how to do so ?

Comment: What do you mean "with a makefile already configured"? You will always need to keep your sources for Makefile synchronized with your project architecture (you can use IDE to do it) and rebuild the Makefile with each architecture change.

Comment: I added an example to make things clearer. 
Considering the synchronization, I suppose tools like `automake` will be enough, but I don't see a project generation option.

Comment: `autotools` are not that easy to grasp, I'd recommend using `cmake`. And it will create the `Makefile` as a part of the build process, you only need to keep the project architecture information in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @fxm I use a Makefile snippet and a Vim user command `:CPP` to do roughly this. I don't feel the need to have more magic added (you could probably use IDEs in the first place, then)

Comment: @sehe I guess I'll use an IDE, then (I'm not too much into Vim :p ).

Comment: FTR: I loved `arborescence` in the title. I also think it conveyed important information: this OP likely knows where is towel is (although obviously, I'm confounded how he simultaneously doesn't know how to operate a life vessel (Vim))

Comment: Why not write your own "little" shell-script (.bat on windows or .sh on *nix) which prepares a new Source dir with CMakeLists.txt, makefile, src/ folder, etc?

Comment: @Andre I don't like to feel I'm reinventing the wheel, which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IDE for that. E.g. [KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/) is able to create basic `CMake`-based project and help you with the project architecture management.

Answer (score 0):

check this quick start guide: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=CMake+Quick+Start+Guide

Comment: It isn't what I'm looking for, since it generates a makefile from an existing project (what I want is the opposite).